# I am not able to figure out the logical problem in the insert method of binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I try to develop a simple insertOperation in Java for the binary tree I am not successful.

My package consists of three classes (Tree, Node, and Main)
How is there any logical thinking mistake? I do not need to be recorded with different code. On internet, there are examples running. I think might be running but it doesn't.

```
public class Node {

    Node left = null;
    Node right = null;
    float value = 0;

    public Node(float value) {

        this.value = value;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
}


import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Tree {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Tree.class.getName());

    Node root;

    public Tree() {
        root = null;
    }


    public void insert(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Einzufügendes Objekt ist Null");
    }

    if (root == null) {
        root = node;

        log.info("root.value:" + root.value);

    } else if (root.value > node.value) {

        if (node.left == null) {

            root.left = node;
            log.info("node.left.value: " + root.left.value);
        }

        else {

            log.info("insert(root.left): " + root.left.value);
            insert(root.left);
        }

    } else {

        if (node.right == null) {

            root.right = node;
            log.info("node.right.value: " + root.right.value);
        }

        else {

            log.info("insert(node.right): " + root.right.value);

            insert(root.right);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Expected result is when I perform this executed my insertOperation with an 
other running methode from internet:

```
Juli 27, 2019 6:13:31 NACHM. Main main
INFORMATION: Rot:----------------------------
Juli 27, 2019 6:13:31 NACHM. Main main
INFORMATION: tree.root.value1.0
Juli 27, 2019 6:13:31 NACHM. Main main
INFORMATION: Linker Teilbaum:--------------------------
Juli 27, 2019 6:13:31 NACHM. Main main
INFORMATION: tree.root.left.value)-7.0
Juli 27, 2019 6:13:31 NACHM. Main main
INFORMATION: tree.root.left.left.value)-8.0
Juli 27, 2019 6:13:31 NACHM. Main main
INFORMATION: root.left.right.value-7.0
Juli 27, 2019 6:13:31 NACHM. Main main
INFORMATION: tree.root.left.right.right.value-0.4
Juli 27, 2019 6:13:31 NACHM. Main main
INFORMATION: Rechter Teilbaum:--------------------------
Juli 27, 2019 6:13:31 NACHM. Main main
INFORMATION: root.right.value2.0
Juli 27, 2019 6:13:31 NACHM. Main main
INFORMATION: root.right.right.value3.0
Juli 27, 2019 6:13:31 NACHM. Main main
INFORMATION: root.right.left.value1.0
Juli 27, 2019 6:13:31 NACHM. Main main
INFORMATION: root.right.right.right.value10.0
```

This is tree which should be created

```
     1
  /     \
-7       2
```

/  \     / \ 
 -8   -7   1   3
       \        \ 
       -4       10

Comment: What is `insertOne()` ?

Comment: One problem is that when you call `insert()`, you continually check the `root's left or right node`.  So the recursive call does not really do anything to root.  Normally you would not have the `user` worry about `nodes`.  Just call `insert()` with a value and have the tree allocate `nodes` behind the scenes.

Comment: I think that you recursion is incorrect, you call `insert(root.left);`, or `insert(root.right);` but you should pass the `node` you want to insert ! You need to change your method, either by adding the current root as parameter (if you want to stick with recursion) or by removing recursion and keeping a reference to the current node

Comment: @PeterMmm Hi, thank you very much for your prompt reply: I replace the insert method `insertOne()` to the proper one I am calling in the Main-Method . _One problem is that when you call `insert()`, you continually check the root's left or right node. So the recursive call does not really do anything to root_. That is exactly the issue. Let's take the example above. How can achieve with corrections that the recursive check would be running with calling the `insert()` methode with node instead of only with value. I am really excited to get a solution here. Pls help.

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel How can I do your advice within my method `insert(Node node)`? I want to stick with recursion by adding root as parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems.

See my comment in the code below.

```java
            if (root.value < node.value) {
                if (node.right == null) {
                    root.right = new Node(node.value);
                    log.info("node.right.value:" + root.right.value);
                }
            } else { //<--- delete the right(}) curly brace.
                     // because your else clause is in the wrong place
                log.info("insert(node.right):" + root.right.value);
                insert(root.right);
            }
        }
```

And as I said in a comment, you need stop using `root` for comparisons.  The `root` is not changing to reflect the node change in your recursive calls. So you keep replacing the same value over and over again.

Update answer starts here.

Here is the best I could do in keeping your code the same.  The main problem was that you kept using the same value of root over and over again.  So I added an  insert method that took both the root and the node.  I would not have done it this way though.  Here is what I would have done.

1. First pass `values`, not `nodes` to the insert method.
2. Make a `second insert method` that takes a `node` and `value`.
3. If the `root` is null, then create a `node with the value` and assign it.
4. Otherwise, recursively call the `insert(node, value)` using left or right as appropriate.  If `null`, create a new node with value and assign it.

Here is the modified version of yours.  I also added a static print routine.

```java
public class TreeDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Tree t = new Tree();
      t.insert(new Node(-1));
      t.insert(new Node(5));
      t.insert(new Node(8));
      t.insert(new Node(-10));
      t.insert(new Node(4));
      t.insert(new Node(-3));
      t.insert(new Node(9));
      t.insert(new Node(12));

      print(t.root);

   }

   public static void print(Node n) {
      if (n.left != null) {
         print(n.left);
      }
      // print inorder
      System.out.println(n.value);
      if (n.right != null) {
         print(n.right);
      }
   }
}

class Node {

   Node  left  = null;
   Node  right = null;
   float value = 0;

   public Node(float value) {

      this.value = value;
      left = null;
      right = null;
   }
}

class Tree {

   Node root;

   public Tree() {
      root = null;
   }
   public void insert(Node node) {
      if (root == null) {
         root = node;
         return;
      }
      insert(root, node);
   }
   // added this method
   private void insert(Node troot, Node node) {

      if (troot.value > node.value) {
         if (troot.left == null) {
            troot.left = node;
         }
         else {
            insert(troot.left, node);
         }
      }
      else {
         if (troot.value <= node.value) {
            if (troot.right == null) {
               troot.right = node;
            }
            else {
               insert(troot.right, node);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I changed the method a little bit regarding your adivce for curly brace, see above please. When it comes to stop using _root_ for comparisons. Wich node variable should I use instead. Maybe you can post a corrected code of my methode. Please do not recod in a diffrent way because I will understand deeply why this code is not running. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am deeply grateful to you for your voluntary work. You have helped me a lot. I now have to use pen and paper to understand your proposed solution. Understanding data structures and recursive pointers is not easy.